# PHP APC cause server crash on Prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, alternative-php-cache

I run Prestashop 1.6.0.9 on a Debian Wheezy dedicated server with Apache2 and PHP 5.4 with APC and 32Gb of memory on the server.

The shop perfectly run without using APC, but when I enable this little guy, after 2-3 hours, I have this problem:

```
FastCGI: server "/var/www/xxxxx/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-*-80-xxxxx.eu" stderr: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/xxxxx/classes/cache/CacheApc.php on line 50
```

and after an hour, this cause a code 500:

```
FastCGI: comm with server "/var/www/xxxxx/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-*-80-xxxxx.eu" aborted: idle timeout (3000 sec)
```

On line 50 of this file:

```
protected function _set($key, $value, $ttl = 0)
{
    return apc_store($key, $value, $ttl);
}
```

PHP APC configuration is based on this guide: http://gregrickaby.com/the-perfect-apc-configuration/

I just changed some things to to fit with my system. I allow 2Gb to shm_size (32Gb available on the server) and change the mmap_file_mask to /var/temp (folder created and permissions to root).

I don't understand what's the problem with APC. It run perfectly for a couple of hours, then he cause this major problem every time!

Comment: APC is horribly buggy, which is one reason why it's no longer in PHP by default since 5.5. Use memcached instead.

Comment: I read it's not recommended to use memcached if I have only 1 server in my architecture.

Comment: There's a lot of bad advice on the Internet :)

Comment: The advice will be to use memcached or use php 5.5 with OPCache Zend?